# Implementing an interface with more general methods

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface, .net-3.5, polymorphism

I have this interface:

```
Public Interface IDocumentSavingEventArgs
    Inherits IDocumentCancelEventArgs

    Property SuggestedDocName As String
    Property SuppressSaveDialog As Boolean
End Interface
```

which, as shown, inherits from a more general interface `IDocumentCancelEventArgs`.

Then I have this interface:

```
Public Interface IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider
    Inherits IProvider

    Sub DocumentSavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentSavingEventArgs)
End Interface
```

For old pulgins compatibility purposes, I need to implement the latter interface ***also*** using an `e` of type `IDocumentCancelEventArgs`:

```
Public Sub MySavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentCancelEventArgs)
    Implements IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider.DocumentSavingHandler
```

This seems not possible, as the compiler warns me that there is no `DocumentSavingHandler` method with that signature.
At runtime, this should not be an issue, in my opinion, as `MySavingHandler` would accept an `IDocumentSavingEventArgs` for sure, since it's typeof `IDocumentCancelEventArgs`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated before, the compiler is correct. You need to have function signatures which match. I think what may be confusing here is even though you could pass a `IDocumentSavingEventArgs` to a function accepting  `IDocumentCancelEventArgs` the compiler sees these definitions as two separate functions. If you want something more general, you may have to abstract those interfaces to another interface, which I wouldn't recommend since that gets un-maintainable fairly quickly, or you could create an overloaded function in your interface.

```
Public Interface IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider
    Inherits IProvider

    Sub DocumentSavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentSavingEventArgs)
    Sub DocumentSavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentCancelEventArgs)
End Interface
```

In the latter function you can convert the object to whatever you need it to be and then pass it to your main `DocumentSavingHandler` method.

Comment: In my opinion you could pass a `IDocumentSavingEventArgs` to a function accepting a `IDocumentCancelEventArgs`, not viceversa as you wrote.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the overload way (which seems the best) implies I have to modify all plugins which implements `IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider` interface. BTW, this seems to be the unique way. Bounty awarded.

Comment: I'd really appreciate an improvement in future versions of .net framework. Tell me if you think this would not be a good thing and why.

Comment: I can't think off any reason off the top of my head why it shouldn't look through the inheritance tree, but that may be beyond my level of expertise. Anyway microsoft has a webpage set up for requesting Visual Studio features here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for your contribute!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct, since IDocumentCancelEventArgs doesn't inherit from IDocumentSavingEventArgs it can't be cast to IDocumentSavingEventArgs. Then you can test in your implementation if e is IDocumentCancelEventArgs or IDocumentSavingEventArgs.

You need to use the least common denominator IDocumentCancelEventArgs

```
Public Interface IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider
    Inherits IProvider

    Sub DocumentSavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentCancelEventArgs)
End Interface


Public Sub DocumentSavingHandler(sender As Object, e As IDocumentCancelEventArgs) Implements IDocumentSavingHandlerProvider.DocumentSavingHandler

    Dim saveEventArgs As IDocumentSavingEventArgs

    If TypeOf e Is IDocumentSavingEventArgs Then
        saveEventArgs = DirectCast(e, IDocumentSavingEventArgs)
    Else
        ' Do something else....
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: It's quite obvious that I can use `IDocumentCancelEventArgs` and then check if it's type of `IDocumentSavingEventArgs`, that's not I want to do. In my opinion, a method that accept a more general event args should be accepted since normally you can call `MySavingHandler` with an `e` of type `IDocumentCancelEventArgs` or any subclass of that type.

Comment: Note that, in my code, you would NOT cast from `IDocumentCancelEventArgs` to `IDocumentSavingEventArgs` (which could fail), but viceversa (which is always allowed).